# Shopping cart method in grails

Tags: grails, shopping-cart

I am trying to do a shopping cart application. I have used Spring security.

i tried to implement a method at my PurchaseOrder domain as follows:

```
public void addToItems(Products products){

    def purchaseItem = items?.find{it.products == products} 

    if (purchaseItem == null){
        if (items == null){
            items = []
        }
        items.add(new PurchaseItem(products:products,purchaseOrder:this,quantity:1,price:products.price))
    }
    else{  
        purchaseItem.quantity += 1
        purchaseItem.price = products.price
    }

}
```

and this at UserController.groovy

```
def addToCart = {

    def products = Products.get(params.productsId)

    if (products == null){
        flash.error = "Could not add product to cart! Could find product with id [${params.productsId}]."
        redirect(controller:'userInfo',action:'productSearch')
    }

    def purchaseOrderInstance = PurchaseOrder.findByUser(currentUser())
    if (purchaseOrderInstance == null){
        purchaseOrderInstance = new PurchaseOrder(user:currentUser())
    }

    purchaseOrderInstance.addToItems(products)

    purchaseOrderInstance.save(flush:true)


    redirect(action:'cart')
}
```

but i got this error:

```
Message: No signature of method: com.shop.PurchaseOrder.addToItems() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]
Possible solutions: addToItems(java.lang.Object), addToItems(com.shop.Products), getItems()
    Line | Method
->>  118 | doCall    in com.shop.UserInfoController$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I am not sure where I might have gone wrong and what does the error mean?

Comment: Try adding `return` after your redirect.

Comment: i have tried but it still returned me the same error.

Comment: Did you add the `return` after the redirect in the if statment or the one at the end of the addToCart closure?

Comment: i added at the end of the addToCart closure. tried adding after if statement but i get an error:

Could not add product to cart! Could not find product with id [null].

Comment: Apparently, your `params.productsId` is null so the `Products.get()` returns no element.

Comment: but i have added products into the database. don't understand why it will return me null value.